# Can't access filesystem from PC anymore

Tags: samsung, tablet, troubleshooting

Starting a couple of weeks ago.. I can't access the file system from my PC on my Samsung tablet..

When connecting the tablet via USB to my PC I never get the dialog box where you choose whether  or not the PC can have access to the file system

When connecting my Samsung phone on the same USB port and using the same USB cable it works fine!?

Have also tried to reset the tablet..

Comment: Have you checked the notification center if there's any that reads "USB connected for charging"?

Comment: When I plug the tablet I can only hear the system sound when charging starts and the battery icon changes to "charging state".. There are no notifications

Comment: Try another cable. The data pins in this cable may have disconnected.

Comment: as said.. the cable works fine with my phone :)

Comment: Things to try 1. Blow dry the port of  2 Change ports. 3.Uninstall all  USB drivers from the PC, reinstall and reboot

Comment: Did you try `adb`?

Comment: what do you mean by `adb`

Comment: @clarkk  If you have USB debugging enabled you could use `adb push` and `adb pull` to get/send files to your device (you will need Android SDK to get `adb`).

Comment: Have you ruled the possibility of faulty MTP drivers eps if you using Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my phone. The USB cable was fine (I checked it with another phone like you) but when I tried it with my phone, it only charged my phone without showing any option for connection. It turned out that the **usb port** (usb connector) of the phone was damaged. Out of the two usb data wires (not the power wires), one was broken. I would therefore  suggest you to get your ***tablet's usb port*** (connector) checked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you pulling down your notification bar, clicking the notification then hitting the "Connect USB storage" button? You can also get to this by Menu > Settings > Wireless and network > USB utilities and hit "Connect storage to PC". In this case, you will plug in your phone after you hit the button.

If you're doing this, the last thing I can think of is your computer has a USB driver issue or your cable went bad.

source: https://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-galaxy-s-ii-epic-4g-touch/154789-cant-access-my-files-phone-computer-anymore.html

You asked same question there. Do you solved your problem?